# Unable to apply code first migrations to mysql database

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am working on asp.net mvc with EF code first model. I am trying to apply migrations using EF code first to my project. I am using MySql database. currently i am using EF 4.3.1 version and mysql connector/.net of 6.6.4.0 version. I am successfully add migrations to my project that means i execute series of commands that gave no errors for me. I have followed these steps,

```
PM> Enable-Migrations

PM> Add-Migration InitialMigration

PM> update-database -verbose
```

these steps create Migration folder to my project and inside Migration folder it creates configuration and timestamp_Initialmigration files, in configuration file i have added following code.

```
SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
```

after that i have added one field to my class like,

```
public int newprop{get; set;}
```

after that i execute update-database -verbose command in PM console.

when i execute my application it throws an error like,

**"Unknown column 'Extent1.newprop' in 'field list'"**

please guide me why i am getting this error does  i went to the wrong way please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

If your not using automatic  migrations

Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion());

```
 public class MyMigrationConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>
    {
        public MyMigrationConfiguration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true; // Are you using this ?????
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        }
    }
```

Then you need to tell EF using the PM Commandlet to add another migration and update the database.

```
PM> Enable-Migrations  //already done this ?
PM> Add-Migration myLabel
PM> Update-Database
```

Search for "code based migrations" on web for help

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late to answer OP... But since it pops up as my first hit on google, ill go ahead anyways :)

The problem here is, that there are a number of restrictions on MySQL as compared to MSSQL. 
* In particular with mysql on casesensitive filesystems (linux hosts), table names may not include capitalized letters. 
* Also keys are restricted to 767 bytes and should/must be integer types. 
* Then there is a problem in parts of the migration generators from Mysql.Data package. For instance when renaming, 'dbo' is not stripped away.

Have a look at this [guide on insidemysql.com](http://insidemysql.com/how-to-use-mysql-for-your-asp-net-identity-provider-with-a-custom-primary-key/). It describes how to reconfigure the Aspnet.Identity stack for using `int` in the `TKey` typecast.

I have a project where i also have hooked into HistoryContext, allowing to alter structure of __MigrationHistory. It renames and resizes the table/columns. There's also the remake of IdentityConfig - so have a look at

1. https://github.com/mschr/ASP.NET-MVC5.MySql-Extended-Bootstrap/tree/master/my.ns.entities/DbContexts/MigrationConfig
2. https://github.com/mschr/ASP.NET-MVC5.MySql-Extended-Bootstrap/tree/master/my.ns.entities/IdentityConfig

Then hook it up with your context (see [IdentityDbContext](https://github.com/mschr/ASP.NET-MVC5.MySql-Extended-Bootstrap/blob/master/my.ns.entities/DbContexts/IdentityDb.cs)) and enable the mentioned `MySqlMigrationScriptGenerator` and `HistoryContextFactory` in your Migrations.Configuration class (see my [IdentitiyMigrations.Configuration](https://github.com/mschr/ASP.NET-MVC5.MySql-Extended-Bootstrap/blob/master/my.ns.entities/DbContexts/IdentityMigrations/Configuration.cs))