# Entity Framework Multiple DbContexts With Multiple MySql Schemas

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I am trying to implement two DbContexts which map to two seperate schemas/databases within MySql with a foreign key between them.

I understand questions similar to this have been asked before, but I can't find an answer in relation to **MySql**

I am using code first but and I'm getting the following error when I do Update-Database:

> MultipleDbContext.ApplicationUser: : EntityType 'ApplicationUser' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> ApplicationUsers: EntityType: EntitySet 'ApplicationUsers' is based on type 'ApplicationUser' that has no keys defined.

These are my 2 DbContexts:

**ApplicationDbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("ApplicationDBContext") {}

    public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationConfiguration());
    }
}

public class ApplicationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Application>
{
    public ApplicationConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.ApplicationID);
        Property(x => x.ApplicationID).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.ApplicationName).IsRequired();
        HasRequired(x => x.PrimaryUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.UserID);
    }
}
```

**ApplicationUserDbContext**

```
public class ApplicationUserDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationUserDbContext() : base("UserDBContext") {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUserConfiguration());
    }
}

public class ApplicationUserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUserConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.UserID);
        Property(x => x.UserID).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

This is my update database statement:

> update-database -ConfigurationTypeName MultipleDbContext.Migrations.Configuration

Thanks!

EDIT - Adding Entity Objects

```
public class Application
{
    public int ApplicationID { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser PrimaryUser { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem probably is, that you have string property as a the primary key for your User and the length of this key is too long for MySql. I believe the limitation is 96 characters for keys (767 bytes).

A way to handle this would be to take only a subset of the string property and apply this to the key. To make the point clear, the following shows a key, which is only 4 chars long.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foo` (
  `id` varchar(128),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`(4)),
)
```

I'd suggest going all in with integer primary keys for the Aspnet.Identity stack - and also make tablenames all lowercase, since this would be an issue on mysql server hosted via case-sensitive filesystems.

This [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mschr/ASP.NET-MVC5.MySql-Extended-Bootstrap/) is kinda overkill as an example, but im pointing out a few [points in the code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913126/unable-to-apply-code-first-migrations-to-mysql-database/40315749#40315749)

Also this answer has a [nice walkthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825001/customising-the-owin-katana-usermanager-factory-behaviour/27847167#27847167)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm using an int for both primary keys. I'm not using Identity, I just named the objects similar names.

Comment: Ah, i missed the part that you have split up into two different database connections. It is simply not possible to have one context join a query with another context. What youre essentially doing via foreign key mapping is `select * from Application app join User on App.X = User.Y` in *one single query*. You cannot